# Deleting objects in S3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am making an android app in which multiple people can delete the same object from the S3 bucket. **If the object does not exist , AWS returns a success message instead of giving an exception.** In such a case, how am i supposed to know who has deleted the object if many people try deleting the object at the exact same time?

Answer (score 2):

S3 is not designed for determining who deleted an objected.  If everyone is doing it at the same time, why is it relevant which actual call caused the deletion?  It is not necessarily representative of real world order of operations, so it may not be giving you the information you are looking for.

If you really need to know, then you might need to implement some sort of lock mechanism (perhaps DynamoDB with conditional consistent read/write?)

Comment: So what happens if I try to delete and access the object at the same time?

Comment: Please create a new Question rather than asking additional question in the Comments section.